# MSSQL: How to increment a int-column grouped by another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table:

```
UserId | Idx
1      | 0
1      | 1
1      | 3
1      | 5
2      | 1
2      | 2
2      | 3
2      | 5
```

And I want to update the Idx column that it is correctly incremented grouped by UserId column:

```
UserId | Idx
1      | 0
1      | 1
1      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 0
2      | 1
2      | 2
2      | 3
```

I know its possible with T-SQL (with Cursor), but is it also possible with a single statement?

Thank you

Comment: [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (A cursor is an awful way to update these values).

Comment: Do `Idx` values get rearranged to control some form of presentation order? If so, trying to eliminate gaps in the stored form is often unnecessary - you can generate contiguous numbering during `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *correlated* subquery :

```
update t
     set idx = coalesce((select count(*) 
                         from table as t1 
                         where t1.userid = t.userid and t1.idx < t.idx
                        ), 0
                       );
```

Comment: @Powerslave . . . Although the logic works, this is definitely not the best approach in SQL Server

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . I have considered this as once because `update` is not daily running statement. So, that just fine for one or two time executions.

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER() with Partition

```
   update tablex set Idx=A.Idx
   from tablex T
   inner join 
   (
      select UserID ,ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER By UserID)-1 Idx
      from tablex       
   ) A on T.ID=A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by idx) - 1 as new_idx
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set idx = new_idx
    where new_idx <> new_idx;
```

This should be the fastest method for solving this problem.